# How to make bool print true once the conditions are met on Flutter with Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I want to print `true` when the `bool` becomes `true`.

For example, I made a number in the database that is `DateTime.now().minute +5` and when I put bool `s = DateTime.now().minute==ds['stamp']` and then put `print(s)`. It prints `false`.

How do I make it so that when it becomes `true` it prints `true`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this out

```
(DateTime.now().minute==ds['stamp']) ? print("true") : print("false");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy/paste this instead of print(s) -

```
s ? print("true") : print("false");
```